# Elliptic integrals using complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-integrals

I wonder if there is any way using complex analysis to solve the following integral
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+\cos^2\theta}d\theta$$

My first question is:

> is it correct to substitute $z=e^{i\theta}$ to obtain$$\oint_{|z|=1}{1\over iz}\sqrt{1+{1\over 4}(z+z^{-1})^2}dz$$

In case of affirmative answer to the first one, my second question is:

> How can we find the singularities of the integrand of the first question and find the residues in them to solve the elliptic integral?

My last question:

> What can be said about$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\cos n\theta}d\theta$$when $\{a_n\}$ are proper real values such that the integrand is defined over $\Bbb R$?

Comment: It's a complete elliptic integral ($4 \sqrt{2} E(1/2)$ according to Mathematica) with no expression in terms of simpler constants as far as I know, so whatever the residue computation would be, I suppose it would just lead you back to the original integral.

Comment: Thank you. Can you also say a similar argument for my last question?

Comment: The last one is a Fourier series of an even periodic function. That even function could have an anti-derivative, or not.

Comment: @HansLundmark: actually both $K(1/2)$ and $E(1/2)$ can be written in terms of $\pi$ and $\Gamma(1/4)$, by Legendre's identity.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: OK, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $z= e^{i \theta}, dz= ie^{i \theta}d\theta, d\theta= i dz/z$  you get

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+\cos^2\theta}d\theta= \int_{|z|} \sqrt{1+\frac14(z+z^{-1})^2}\frac{idz}{z}$$
Where by definition $\int_{|z|=1} f(z)dz=  \int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{it}) i e^{it}dt$

We need to be careful with the branch of $\sqrt{.}$, with the one making the integrand continuous on $|z|=1$, we have to locate the zeros/poles of $1+\frac14(z+z^{-1})^2$ to find if the integrand is analytic on $|z|=1$ or not.

For the poles there is only one at $0$ of order $2$ thus $\sqrt{1+\frac14(z+z^{-1})^2}$ is meromorphic at $0$. For the zeros 
$$(z+z^{-1})^2 +4=0, z+z^{-1} = \pm 2i, z^2\pm 2i z+1= 0, z = \frac{\pm 2i\pm \sqrt{(2i)^2-4}}{2}=\pm i \pm i\sqrt{2}$$

Thus there are two simple zeros inside the unit disk at $\pm i(\sqrt{2}-1)$. This is a major problem which means the integrand is analytic on $\sqrt{2}-1<|z|\le 1$ but not on $|z|= \sqrt{2}-1$ and
$$\int_{|z|=1} \sqrt{1+\frac14(z+z^{-1})^2}\frac{idz}{z}=\lim_{r \to \sqrt{2}-1}\int_{|z|=r} \sqrt{1+\frac14(z+z^{-1})^2}\frac{idz}{z}$$

$$\ne\lim_{r \to 0}\int_{|z|=r} \sqrt{1+\frac14(z+z^{-1})^2}\frac{idz}{z}= 2i\pi Res(\sqrt{1+\frac14(z+z^{-1})^2}\frac{i}{z},z=0)$$

> So your integral cannot be solved using the residue theorem